# Kubernetes Ingress controllers for wildcard url mapping

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I need for each of my users to access a service at a custom url eg. abccompany.mycloudapp.com , each service being a kubernetes service I'm looking at ingress controllers but I need a way to use a wildcard host field and somehow read the value into the path: and service: fields ; here's a sample ingress controller of what I have in mind:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: test
spec:
 rules:
 - host: *.bar.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /{{ value of * in * .bar.com }}
       backend:
         serviceName: {{value of * in *.bar.com }}Svc
         servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the stock controllers you will be able to switch on hostname and go to different backends services. It sounds like you don't want to enumerate all the subdomains -> service mappings, in which case you probably need to write your own controller that writes out an nginx config that uses $http_host in the appropriate proxy_pass or redirect lines. Give it a shot (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers) and file bugs in that same repo if you need help.

Comment: I guess I will have to write my own controller after all , thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you you end up coming up with a solution to this?