# routing wildcard domain to different paths in nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

how do I achieve something similar to this.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /c/{word-maching-wildcard}

  name: some-route
  namespace: prod
spec:
  rules:
     - host: "*.example.com" # {hello}.example.com -> hello.example.com/hello
       http:
        paths:
         - backend:
            serviceName: svc
            servicePort: 8080
           path: /
```

Is there any way to capture the matching word in the subdomain and append it in the path before routing to the upstream service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official doc:

> Regular expressions and wild cards are not supported in the
> `spec.rules.host` field. Full hostnames must be used.

See: [nginx-ingress-matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/).

However I have found similar problem which advice to write your own controller that writes out an nginx config that uses `$http_host` in the appropriate `proxy_pass` or redirect lines.

Read more: [wildcard-url-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028223/kubernetes-ingress-controllers-for-wildcard-url-mapping).